# C# UW Navigation between frame give definition error why?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I use this method many times, but now, it give error:
'MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'Page2Button_Click' and no extension method 'Page2Button_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'MainPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) App11   c:\users\serge\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App11\App11\MainPage.xaml  13

[Code XAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Dys.jpg)
[C# code behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60HF8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The code behind event handler only defines a `Page2GButton_Click` event. Notice the extra `G`.